# How Do I Deliver Previously GZipped Cached HTML Files Via PHP?

Tags: php, gzip

**Situation**

I have a cache developed for my website wherein I currently check each page request to see if there is a static, cached version of the page and then, if browser supported, I gzip the page and hand it back to the browser.

**Current Code**

```
$hash = md5('http://mydomain.com'.$url);
$fl = substr($url, 1, 1);
if(file_exists('/home/myaccount/public_html/cache/'.$fl.'/'.$hash.'.html') && $_GET['cache'] != 'off' && $fl!=''):
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    include 'cache/'.$fl.'/'.$hash.'.html';
elseif(file_exists('/home/myaccount/public_html/cache/'.$hash.'.html') && $_GET['cache'] != 'off'):
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    include 'cache/'.$hash.'.html';
else:
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace('?cache=off','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    include 'interface/index.php'; 
endif;
```

**Desired Change**

I would like to change it so that the files on the server are gzipped already. I already know how to gzip the files and set them on the server. However, I would like to know how to modify this portion of the script so that it checks if gzip is supported by the browser and then simply hands them the gzipped version of the file. If it is not supported, it will un-gzip it and hand it back to the server.

**Purpose**

This will accomplish several things. First, it will use less space on the server to store the files. Second, it will trim a few milliseconds off the time by not having to gzip them on each page request since the majority of browsers will accept the gzipped format. Instead, it will only have to un-gzip the files for a very few unsupported browsers. Third, it is an opportunity to learn more about the way that php works with gzipped files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work out an answer. Here it is for anyone that is interested:

```
$hash = md5('http://mydomain.com'.$url);
$fl = substr($url, 1, 1);
if(file_exists('/home/myaccount/public_html/cache/'.$fl.'/'.$hash.'.html.gz') && $_GET['cache'] != 'off' && $fl!=''):
    if (strstr($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], "gzip")):
        header("X-Compression: gzip");
        header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
        readfile('cache/'.$fl.'/'.$hash.'.html.gz');
    else:
        $gz = gzopen ('cache/'.$fl.'/'.$hash.'.html.gz', "r");
        $contents = gzread ($gz, 1000000);
        echo $contents;
    endif;
elseif(file_exists('/home/myaccount/public_html/cache/'.$hash.'.html.gz') && $_GET['cache'] != 'off'):
    if (strstr($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], "gzip")):
        header("X-Compression: gzip");
        header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
        readfile('cache/'.$hash.'.html.gz');
    else:
        $gz = gzopen ('cache/'.$hash.'.html.gz', "r");
        $contents = gzread ($gz, 1000000);
        echo $contents;
    endif;
else:
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace('?cache=off','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    include 'interface/index.php'; 
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see only the third reason good enough to implement this thing in php, but then you should discover the solution yourself.

As for the first two reasons, Apache has two options:

- [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html) may be used to send pre-gzip'ed file instead of
  its uncompressed version to the supporting client
- [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html) may be used to decompress (inflate) the output
  stream for clients that do not support compressed transfer encoding